# ReactiveRedisOperations not saving object in Redis

Tags: redis, reactive-programming, lettuce, spring-data-redis-reactive

I am using ReactiveRedisOperations to save data objects in Redis and this call returns a Mono as per the api.
I notice that if I don't do anything with this Mono return than this code does not do anything.
Just trying to understand how this works.
I would like below code to save every Object to Redis in this loop, however it does not do so, please share what is missing here.

```
 for (SomeObject obj : list) {
 reactiveRedisOperations.opsForHash().put(key, hashKey, obj).map(b -> obj); }
```

On the other side if i return the Mono result from similar code via a rest service response than it seems to save in Redis correctly, not sure why this is this way. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is a quirk of reactive streams, not Lettuce.

Unlike a completable future which begins execution when it's created, a stream won't begin executing (the command isn't sent) until a consumer has subscribed to it.

I believe this is to facilitate backpressure, so a slow consumer isn't flooded with data by the producer.

Some nice reading -> https://blog.knoldus.com/working-with-project-reactor-reactive-streams/

Answer (score 0):

If you return a `Mono`, to the underlying web framework, which generally will handle `subscribe`(ing) to this `Mono`, the respective operation will trigger resulting in whatever side-effects such as data being created in your *Redis* datastore.

Shall you wish to have your operations executed, you should do the same, i.e. `subscribe` to the publisher (`Mono`, or `Flux`) or return these data wrappers to whatever calling function you would know will handle this for you as in the aforementioned example:

```
Flux.fromIterable(list)
    .flatMap(obj -> reactiveRedisOperations.opsForHash().put(key, hashKey, obj))
    .subscribe();
```